# Find path with current user C:\users\%USERNAME%\... in .vbs

Tags: vbscript

I won't to set `objFolder` path, but I can't get current username

```
objShell.NameSpace(C:\users\%CurrentUser%\AppData)
```

Code:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows")
```

Or can I replace `objShell.NameSpace("C:\somepath")` different method?

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows")
```

Comment: Learn from `Wscript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ).ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%\AppData")`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use `Shell.Namespace` you might want to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-namespace).
It says:

> vDir [in]
>
> Type: Variant
>
> The folder for which to create the Folder object. This can be a string
>   that specifies the path of the folder or one of the
>   **ShellSpecialFolderConstants** values. Note that the constant names found
>   in ShellSpecialFolderConstants are available in Visual Basic, but not
>   in VBScript or JScript. In those cases, the numeric values must be
>   used in their place.

when you follow the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants) for **ShellSpecialFolderConstants**
You'll find

> ssfSTARTMENU  0x0b (11). File system directory that contains Start menu
>   items. A typical path is C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu.

Which is I one level deeper than what you are looking for. So from that folder you can just go up one level and you have the folder you need.

Something like this should work:

```
option explicit

const ssfSTARTMENU = 11

sub main
    msgbox getWindowsFolder().Self.Path
end sub

function getWindowsFolder()
    dim shell
    Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    dim startMenuFolder
    set startMenuFolder = shell.Namespace(ssfSTARTMENU)
    set getWindowsFolder = startMenuFolder.ParentFolder
end function

main
```